# Editing multiple NFC tags simultaneously

Tags: nfc

I would like to implement a URL in many NFC tags.
I'm talking about hundreds, thousands.
Whats is the easiest way for doing this, which type of readers is supporting this option and how can it be done ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case you really want to pre-personalize tousand of tags, I'd suggest you directly ask a personalization bureau or a tag manufacturer to do this for you, as this can already be done during the production process.

If you want to do it on your own, it pends on the kind of tag you want to use (from a technical perspective). Also the reading/writing performance should be good. I do have good experiences with the Omnikey 5321 as well as the ARC122.

Comment: Hi, I have ntag203 tags, how can I do it ?

Comment: What would you like to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I used to purchase nfc tag in bulks with pre-encoding content in each nfc tags from G[ee nfc limited](http://www.geenfc.com/en/Products/Tags/Papernfctag/). They really do wonderful work and fast delivery in less than 1 week, and their nfc tags are extremely cheap, :)